# EE3.0 - custom member field not showing up in registration form in CP

Tags: members, ee

I have created a custom member field in the CP and set it to "required", "show in registration" and "show in profile". However, it doesn't show up in the form when I register a new member in the CP and it doesn't show up in their profile when I go to edit a member.

I can see that the field was created correctly because it is in the exp_member_fields table. Am I doing something wrong that it is not in the form to register anyone and that I can create a new member without filling out that field? I am not using any plugins currently (developing a new site).

Thanks for any help anyone can give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I decided to look at this since we need this for our site. I have a fix for the new member registration page (not letting them be edited from the CP yet, that is next).  Using EE3.0.0, in file system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Members/Create.php, there are two places that need to be changed.

To show fields, change function index() and add code to actually check for custom fields. Here is how I did it (I’m sure there are better ways):

Line 65 - 134 changed:

```
$tmp_final[] = array(
            'title' => 'member_group',
            'desc' => 'member_group_desc',
            'fields' => array(
                'group_id' => array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'choices' => $choices,
                    'value' => (isset($choices[5]) && $choices[5] == 'Members') ? 5 : '',
                    'required' => TRUE
                )
            )
        );
    $tmp_final[] = array(
            'title' => 'username',
            'fields' => array(
                'username' => array('type' => 'text', 'required' => TRUE)
            )
        );
    $tmp_final[] = array(
            'title' => 'mbr_email_address',
            'fields' => array(
                'email' => array('type' => 'text', 'required' => TRUE)
            )
        );
    $tmp_final[] = array(
            'title' => 'password',
            'desc' => 'password_desc',
            'fields' => array(
                'password' => array('type' => 'password', 'required' => TRUE)
            )
        );
    $tmp_final[] = array(
            'title' => 'password_confirm',
            'desc' => 'password_confirm_desc',
            'fields' => array(
                'confirm_password' => array('type' => 'password', 'required' => TRUE)
            )
        );

    //Get custom member fields 
    $cust_fields = ee()->db->from('member_fields')->where('m_field_reg', 'y')->order_by('m_field_id', 'asc')->get();

    if ($cust_fields->num_rows() > 0) {
        // Have custom fields. Add fields to registration form and for validation.
        foreach ($cust_fields->result_array() as $row)
        {
            if ($row['m_field_type'] == 'select') {
                $choices = array();
                $value = 0;
                $choice = explode("\n", $row['m_field_list_items']);
                $c = 0;
                foreach($choice as $choi) 
                {
                    $choices[$c] = $choi;
                    $c++;
                }   
            } else {
                $value = '';
            }   
            if ($row['m_field_required'] == 'n') 
                $required = FALSE;
            else 
                $required = TRUE;


            $tmp_final[] = array(
                'title' => $row['m_field_label'],
                'desc' => $row['m_field_description'],
                'fields' => array(
                    'field_id_'.$row['m_field_id'] => array(
                        'type' => $row['m_field_type'], 
                        'choices' => $choices,
                        'required' => $required,
                        'value' => $value
                    )
                )
            );
            if ($row['m_field_required'] == 'y') {
                $tmp_validation[] = array(
                     'field'   => 'field_id_'.$row['m_field_id'],
                     'label'   => $row['m_field_label'],
                     'rules'   => 'required'
                 );
            }
        }
    }
    $vars['sections'][] = $tmp_final;

    $tmp_validation[] = array(
             'field'   => 'group_id',
             'label'   => 'lang:member_group',
             'rules'   => 'required|integer|callback_valid_group_id'
        );
    $tmp_validation[] = array(
             'field'   => 'username',
             'label'   => 'lang:username',
             'rules'   => 'required|trim|valid_username'
        );
    $tmp_validation[] = array(
             'field'   => 'email',
             'label'   => 'lang:email',
             'rules'   => 'required|valid_email'
        );
    $tmp_validation[] = array(
            'field'    => 'password',
            'label'    => 'lang:password',
            'rules'    => 'required|valid_password[username]'
        );
    $tmp_validation[] = array(
             'field'   => 'confirm_password',
             'label'   => 'lang:confirm_password',
             'rules'   => 'required|matches[password]'
        );

    ee()->form_validation->set_rules($tmp_validation);
```

Next, to get the fields to actually be inserted into the database, a couple of changes need to be made in function register_member(), at lines 292-294:

`if ($this->input->post(‘field_id_’.$row[‘m_field_id’]) !== FALSE)
{
$cust_fields[‘field_id_’.$row[‘m_field_id’]] = $this->input->post(‘field_id_’.$row[‘m_field_id’], TRUE);
}`

since the names of the columns in exp_member_data have dropped the ‘m_’ prefix on the column names.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug that has been reported to Ellislab - https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21118/member-custom-fields-not-showing-on-profile-edit